# Subconsultas com declaração SELECT no Sqlite

Tags: sqlite3

Tenho que retornar dois valores na minha consulta e não sei se é possível fazer isso em um único select... Queria uma explicação melhor para entender como fazer um subselect no Sqlite.

Tenho os seguintes campos:

```
CREATE TABLE [LANCAMENTO](
    [ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    [VALOR] DECIMAL(8, 2), 
    [DATE_BUY] DATETIME, 
    [DESCRIPTION] VARCHAR(150), 
    [ID_FORMA] INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES FORMAS([ID]), 
    [ID_CATAO] INTEGER, 
    [ID_CATEGORIA] INTEGER REFERENCES CATEGORIA([ID]), 
    [TYPE_RELEASE] VARCHAR(1), 
    [ORGANIZATION] VARCHAR(50), 
    [ID_USUARIO] INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES USUARIOS([ID]));
```

eu tentei fazer a consulta assim:

```
SELECT
  RESULT_D.VALOR AS VALOR_D,
  RESULT_C.VALOR AS VALOR_C
FROM
  (select sum(VALOR) form LANCAMENTO where  TYPE_RELEASE ='D') as RESULT_D,
  (select sum(VALOR) form LANCAMENTO where  TYPE_RELEASE ='C') as RESULT_C
```

Só que não funciona eu tentei ver nesse *[Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_sub_queries.htm)* e não entende como se faz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão é que você esta criando um select baseado em variáveis criadas no `FROM` quando deveria ser diretas no `SELECT`.

Altere sua query para.

```
SELECT
 (select sum(VALOR) form LANCAMENTO where  TYPE_RELEASE ='D') as VALOR_D,
 (select sum(VALOR) form LANCAMENTO where  TYPE_RELEASE ='C') as VALOR_C
```

ou

```
SELECT
  saida.RESULT_D AS VALOR_D,
  saida.RESULT_C AS VALOR_C
FROM
(
  (select sum(VALOR) form LANCAMENTO where  TYPE_RELEASE ='D') as RESULT_D,
  (select sum(VALOR) form LANCAMENTO where  TYPE_RELEASE ='C') as RESULT_C
)saida
```

Comment: Não Funcionou  a ultima...

Comment: não tem como testa aqui, certamente esta faltando alguma coisa, qual foi o erro ? mas para questa de performance a primeira query e mais limpa e melhor.

Comment: A primeira que você postou funcionou, só a ultima que não por isso vou ficar com a primeira pôs já resolver o problema. O erro que deu na segunda consulta foi esse                                                                                
     near "LANCAMENTO": syntax error SQL Statement:
     SELECT
            saida.RESULT_D AS VALOR_D,
            saida.RESULT_C AS VALOR_C
     FROM (...

Answer (score 0):

O **SQL** abaixo (*exatamente como está*) já traz o resultado que você deseja:

```
SELECT
  (select sum(VALOR) from LANCAMENTO where  TYPE_RELEASE ='D') as RESULT_D,
  (select sum(VALOR) from LANCAMENTO where  TYPE_RELEASE ='C') as RESULT_C
```